# About views in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, view

I am just on the beginning to learn CodeIgniter, I have one controller named home.php and I have 2 views named photo.php and body.php and I want to call the first view in the other. and finally calling body.php on acceuil.php.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you try something by yourself?

Comment: yes.. I'm searching now.. and I did some lignes on my page .. that's why i'm asking u .. to be sure before executing the code :)

Comment: CodeIgniter can nest views, so you can load a view from within another, just try it.  If you see an error message, that is okay, you can figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Try to do this with making a General Temp;ate of your View.
In template add the Header add Footer and in between you will change your code dynamically.

Comment: but i have some composants as div <style ... class=...> witch comport header and body a the same time so i must call header in this div + the body .. after this calling my view in my controllers :/

Answer (score 3):

In the first view page ie in body.php you just write

```
$this->load->view('photo.php');
```

Comment: this is similar to using include

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

in your first view **body.php**

```
$ci =& get_instance();//you have to do this because you are in output library
$ci->load->view('photo.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also load the parent view and pass the child view as a parameter like this

```
$childview = $this->load->view('childview.php');
$this->load->view('parentview.php', array('childview' => $childview))
```

and than in parentview.php you just need to echo the variable $childview.

Answer (score 0):

In your body.php view

```
$this->load->view($content);
Here you can put whatever bod content
```

And in your controller

```
$data['content']='views/photo.php';
$this->load->view('body.php',$data);
```

Above method good for complex view structures like seperate header,footer and body files.But for your one can just do this way as well.

In your body.php

```
$this->load->view('photo.php');
```

And in your controller just load

```
$this->load->view('body.php');
```